# Performance improvement of page where million records are present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some suggestion how to improve the performance of the application, I'm developing MVC 3 ASP.NET Application. From the controller , I'm pulling 50,000 records of type string, All the items i.e 50,000 are added to a HTML Div dynamically using Jquery.

```
   $(div).append("<input type='radio' name='reportType' 
   id='" + item.Item1 + "' value = '" + item.Item2 + "'/>" + item.Item1 ");
```

I see there is considerable amount of time is taken while adding above radio button to parent control i.e HTML `DIV`

The parent HTML `DIV` has `Check box`, on checking that, all the child box must be selected. I see there is considerable amount of time for checking all items

All these items are in Scroll Viewer, Is there a way to improve user experience, Like loading data on Scroll basis some thing like Data Virtualization of **Silverlight** in HTML 5.

I Check all items and Drag on to another part of page, which make Browser to non responsive mode. Can anyone provide me best user experience of these many records with improve Query performance

Comment: Do not add them all to the html, only add the ones that are to be displayed at the same time. If you add all 50k to the DOM the DOM will be slow.

Comment: You are looping through 50K records one at a time and appending them one by one? Redraw hell! You really need a way to page the data or do some sort of endless scroll technique.

Comment: Try taking an HTML save of what you are doing, put that on your web server, and get the browser performance okay on that. If it is still dog-slow, then you may need to re-think your screen complexity. You could try adding elements a block at time, using `setTimeout`, to effectively multitask with the browser. Screens will render visibly slowly, but this is better than locking it up!

Comment: @epascarello: user need all the data , we cant page the data

Comment: I doubt that showing 50,000 items will be of any use to the user. Do you seriously expect him to scroll through and read them one at a time, and select one here and there? What kind of data is it? That is simply too many items for a human to reasonably work with. If that many items must be worked with *as a group*, then is there any need to show those actual items? Instead, present a UI element that represents those items. Upon form submission, the database on the other end knows which ones are desired and performs the action--all without the user dealing with craziness.

Comment: Without knowing the requirements, I am going to say: I love when people say the user needs all of the data. That is normally manager speak, dealt with it plenty of times. Do you get 50,000 results from google, etc? What users need are filters to limit the data. No one is going to scroll through that amount of data to find 1 thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a documentFragment and add the nodes there. And after you finish add the documentFragment to the DOM. Also, it's more efficient to use `createElement` than to use strings. There are a lot of jsperf tests to prove that and there you can also find ways to do it in the most efficient way.

To prevent the browser from completely freezing for a long period of time, you should break your iteration in batches of...1000 item (pure guess). And call that function as many times as you need to finish the job. Keep a counter outside it. Call it with `setTimeout(renderMore, 0)`. At least this will keep the window from freezing.

Depending on your UI and workflows, there might be some other improvements you can apply. But you didn't provide much info about that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Build your HTML string that you want to append.
2. Append it once, after its building is finished.

This will be faster than appending each string.

```
var htmlToAppend = "";
for (var i in items) {
     var item = items[i];
     htmlToAppend = "<input type='radio' name='reportType' id='" + item.Item1 + "' value = '" + item.Item2 + "'/>" + item.Item1;
}

$(div).append(htmlToAppend);
```

Also, I believe that there is a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to display large dataset, try this:

1) Store it in browser memory, use sessionStorage() or localStorage()

2) Minimize DOM, do not write ALL data to DOM, dynamically add & remove the elements.

3) Allow dataset to be searchable, this means a filter function that trims the dataset.

Another recommended way of resolving this is to use [Megalist](http://triceam.github.io/MegaList/), require jQuery and works well for tablet or mobile.